# Redux-firebase: How to access a dispatch action's payload that never makes it to state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image]

```
 const options = {
    name: imageName,
    progress: true
  };

 let uploadedFile = await firebase.uploadFile(
      path,
      file.file,
      null,
      options
    );
```

I am uploading a file with redux-firebase, and I can see the percentage changing on upload progress when inspecting with redux addon. However, as this reducer is closed in the redux-firebase package, how can I go about intercepting/reading this property as I upload a file? The maintainer of the package doesn't look like they will be including a (withprogress) reducer anytime soon (https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/346), but seems like the percent payload was included for future proofing basis. Thank you.

Comment: What is the state in this moment?

Answer (score 1):

In your reducer you need to listen to action FILE_UPLOAD_PROGRESS (it's a constant that can be imported), update state ('percent' property for example), map this state property to the component property and show the progress.